# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_3 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 224, 224, 64)

Tags: python, keras

I have the following code, retrieving data tuple with string and array. I am discarding string from tuple and using array to do prediction.

```
 data=socket.recv_image()
 image_data=tuple(x for x in data if x != 'data-received' )
 image_to_list= list(image_data)
 image = np.array(image_to_list)
 print(image.shape)#(1, 1, 224, 224, 64)
 tmp = np.zeros( image.shape )
 for i in range( 0, 1 ):
       tmp[i,:,:] = tmp[i, :]
       predictions_result = m2.predict( tmp )
       label_vgg16 = decode_predictions( predictions_result )
       print( label_vgg16 )
```

I am retrieving below error

```
File "C:/Users/40227422/Desktop/imagezmq-master/tests/unit_tests/server-b.py", line 57, in <module>
main()
File "C:/Users/40227422/Desktop/imagezmq-master/tests/unit_tests/server-b.py", line 51, in main
 predictions_result = m2.predict( tmp )
File "C:\Users\40227422\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site- 
packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 128, in standardize_input_data
'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
 ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_3 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with 
 shape (1, 1, 224, 224, 64)
```

Comment: The error message is pretty obvious I believe. The model expect 4 dims in input `tmp` in this case, but it has 5 dims. Check your input dim.

Comment: To the reviewer who proposed he `ml` tag: notice that that tag is about "Meta Language", and it is **not** about ML: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info

Comment: Thanks @null for pointing out this, so I want to remove 1 and  need shape to be like this (1,224,224,64)  so I changed it to result = image[0,:,:, :] and its working fine. Thanks

Comment: I don't know how you trained your model, I assume it should be (1,224,224,64), but there's no way I can figure out from what you wrote. Review how you trained your model (input size).

Comment: I am using a pre-trained model and without batch size performing predictions on the video frames